# How to find, across multiple databases, a specific table (common to most/all) that is not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working in an environment where many users have the same (or almost identical) test database set up on a common MSSQL server. We are talking about well over 100 databases for testing purposes. And at the very least, 95+% of them will contain the table I am trying to target.

These test databases are only filled with junk data - I will not be impacting anyone by doing any kind of a search. I am looking at one table, specifically, and I need to determine if any test database has that table actually containing any data at all. It doesn’t matter what the data is, I just need to find a table actually containing any data, so I can determine why that data exists in the first place. (This DB is quite old - almost two decades, so sometimes no-one has a clear answer why something in it exists).

I have been trying to build an SQL statement that iterates through all the databases, and checks that particular table specifically to see if it has any content, to bring back a list of databases that have that table containing data.

So to be specific: I need to find all databases where a specific table has any content at all (`COUNT(*) > 0`). Right now totally stuck with not much of any clues as to how to proceed.

Comment: Every database connector I know requires that you specify which database you are setting a connection to, but what if you used the master table to loop through and set a connection to each database, then run your query? If it returns a count you can add this database name to an array or another table.

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is good to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about asking, answering and all basic rules of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In both methods replace `<tablename>` with the table name*

## Using sp_foreachdb

You can use sp_foreachDb

```
CREATE TABLE ##TBLTEMP(dbname varchar(100), rowscount int)

DECLARE @command varchar(4000) 
SELECT @command = 
'if exists(select 1 from [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME =''<TABLE NAME>'') insert into ##TBLTEMP(dbname,rowscount) select ''[?]'',count(*) from [?].dbo.<tablename>' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command


SELECT * FROM ##TBLTEMP WHERE rowscount > 0

DROP TABLE ##TBLTEMP
```

## Using CURSOR

```
CREATE TABLE ##TBLTEMP(dbname  varchar(100), rowscount int)
DECLARE @dbname  Varchar(100), @strQuery varchar(4000)

DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases
FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @strQuery = 'if exists(select 1 from [' + @dbname +'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME =''<TABLE NAME>'') INSERT INTO ##TBLTEMP(dbname,rowscount) SELECT ''' + @dbname + '' ', COUNT(*) FROM [' + @dbname + '].[dbo].<table name>'

EXEC(@strQuery)

FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @dbname


END

CLOSE csr
DEALLOCATE csr

SELECT * FROM ##TBLTEMP where rowscount > 0
```

**References**

- [Sp MSforeachDB](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Sp_MSforeachDB)
- [Run same command on all SQL Server databases without cursors](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/)
- [DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Using your first example: `'varchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Looks like the `as` does not belong.

Comment: And it looks like that the few databases that don’t actually have the table in question, such as `Master` and `Model`, are causing the first example to fail with an invalid object name. Trying logical workarounds.

Comment: Okay, got obsessed with the Messages tab, which is where the results defaulted to: I am actually getting valid content in the Results tab if I add an `IF EXISTS` to the beginning of the command and do a quick `(SELECT * FROM [?].dbo.<tablename>)` to check for existence before putting a `BEGIN` and `END` around your main block. Thank you!!